# Expression as table name in from clause

Tags: google-bigquery

In BigQuery is there a way to specify the table name in the `FROM` clause using an expression?

For example, say we have data split across multiple tables -- one for each month of the year. 2016_01, 2016_02, 2016_03 and so on. Now we want to create a view for the current month's data. I'm hoping for something like

`SELECT * FROM [project:dataset.${REPLACE(LEFT(CURRENT_DATE(),7),'-','_')}]`

So that the expression is evaluated and results in `SELECT * FROM [project:dataset.2016_08]` as the query being executed.

To carry it even further, let's say there is 1 table for every day. Now the user needs data from a date range 1/1/2016 to 3/31/2016. So we generate our query like so:

```
SELECT * FROM 2016_01_01, 2016_01_02, ...and so on... 2016_03_31
```

The main motivation of this is that long term storage is cheaper. So it makes sense to split the data so you're not writing to the same big table every day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

3 options, given the problem statement:

- You want to write your own expressions to choose tables? `TABLE_QUERY()`

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#table-query

- But since you are doing this with tables partitioned by days, `TABLE_DATE_RANGE()` is less flexible, but more efficient:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/query-reference#table-date-range

- And as Elliott says, partitioned tables are the new recommended way of working with one giant table, while getting the cost benefits:

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables

Comment: Thanks. I'll be using date partitioned tables per Elliott's suggestion. Accepting your answer because it addresses the actual question about expressions to choose tables.

Comment: Thanks for accepting the answer. You can give points to Elliot (and everyone else that gave a correct answer) too. :)

Comment: Thanks, how do you give points? Do you mean upvote the answer?

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen [partitioned tables](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/creating-partitioned-tables)? They are very similar to what you are describing. Partitioned tables allow you to filter on specific date ranges and just be billed for the dates that you query.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about partitioned tables. They solve this exact problem.

Answer (score 1):

If you have existing tables that are not partitioned, another approach is to use Standard SQL wildcard tables. The tables that you wish to query can be specified using a predicate on a special column in the WHERE clause.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/querying-wildcard-tables